# Handling login credentials in a global variables or any

Tags: python, pyqt

this time my problem is with the login credentials, I want to be able to use them in my mainwindow to continue consulting my database, the usage code is as follows:

```
import sys
from sqlprograma import *
from PyQt6.QtCore import QSize, QAbstractTableModel, Qt
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton, QDialog, QDialogButtonBox, QGridLayout, QLabel,QLineEdit, QWidget, QMessageBox, QStatusBar, QVBoxLayout, QTableView, QComboBox
from PyQt6.QtGui import QPalette, QColor, QAction

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
class TableModel(QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, data):
        super(TableModel, self).__init__()
        self._data = data
    def data(self, index, role = Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole):
        if index.isValid():
            if role == Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole or role == Qt.ItemDataRole.EditRole:
                value = self._data.iloc[index.row(), index.column()]
                return str(value)
    def rowCount(self, index):
        return self._data.shape[0]
    def columnCount(self, index):
        return self._data.shape[1]
    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role):
        # section is the index of the column/row.
        if role == Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole:
            if orientation == Qt.Orientation.Horizontal:
                return str(self._data.columns[section])
            if orientation == Qt.Orientation.Vertical:
                return str(self._data.index[section])
class Login(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Impulsa OE")
        self.setFixedSize(400,300)
        self.login_dialog()

    def login_dialog(self):
        button = QPushButton("Ingresar",self)
        button.clicked.connect(self.open_login)
        button.setGeometry(160,130,80,50)

    def open_login(self):
        dialogin.exec()

class LoginDialog(QDialog):
    usuario = null
    contrasena = null
    def __init__(self, parent=Login):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("¡Bienvenida!")
        self.setFixedSize(QSize(300, 200))
        self.titulo = QLabel("Ingrese sus datos para iniciar", self).move(80,45)
        self.dato1 = QLineEdit(self)
        self.dato1.setPlaceholderText("Usuario")
        self.dato1.move(85,80)
        self.dato2 = QLineEdit(self, echoMode=QLineEdit.EchoMode.Password)
        self.dato2.setPlaceholderText("Contraseña")
        self.dato2.move(85,110)
        self.botonconectar = QPushButton("Conectar", self)
        self.botonconectar.clicked.connect(self.conectar_sql)
        self.botonconectar.move(115,150)

    def conectar_sql(self):
        alerta = QMessageBox(QMessageBox.Icon.Critical,"¡Ups!","Usuario y/o contraseña incorrectos")
        self.usuario = self.dato1.text()
        self.contrasena = self.dato2.text()
        self.dato1.clear()
        self.dato2.clear()
        if app_login(self.usuario,self.contrasena) == "public":
            self.conta = Acc()
            self.conta.show()
            self.hide()
            window.close()
        elif app_login(self.usuario,self.contrasena) == "fact":
            pass
            self.factu = Acc()
            self.factu.show()
            self.hide()
            window.close()
        elif app_login(self.usuario,self.contrasena) == "prod":
            pass
            self.produ = Acc()
            self.produ.show()
            self.hide()
            window.close()
        else: alerta.exec()

class Acc(QMainWindow):
    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setFixedSize(700,500)
        self.setWindowTitle("Impulsa OE - Contabilidad")
        menu = self.menuBar()

        self.table = QTableView()
        tablaentidades = entidades(dialogin.usuario,dialogin.contrasena)
        #data = data.astype({'numero_documento':'int'})
        self.model = TableModel(tablaentidades)
        self.table.setModel(self.model)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.table)

window = Login()
dialogin = LoginDialog()
def main():
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

In this way I can use the input data contained in a variable in my main window

Also correcting certain bad practices mentioned by musicamante, removing and ordering my code

Comment: Your code has many issues, for instance: 1. you should not create the QApplication up there, and both creation and execution should always be within the `if __name__ == '__main__':` block; 2. that `self.show` in the `__init__` of `Login` is useless, and you should normally not call `self.show()` in the `__init__` anyway; 3. object names should be explanatory, and classes should always be capitalized: calling the main window class `acc` is a terrible choice for readability and usage; 4. you should use [layout managers](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html); 5. you should not rely on global variables.

Comment: That said, `self.motor` is a member of the `LoginDialog` instance, meaning that in `open_login()` you could access it as `self.dialogin.motors`, **assuming** that the `conectar_sql` function has been called. Unfortunately, that doesn't allow you to directly use it in the main window (not even accessing `window.dialogin.motors`) when you create it, because at that point it doesn't exist yet. You should learn more about [signals and slots](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html) (possibly following [this tutorial](//zetcode.com/gui/pyqt5/eventssignals/)) so that you can connect all your elements.

Comment: @musicamante Thank you, I corrected my code a bit and I managed to achieve my goal, I can surely improve more. Right now I have another question about how to use a column of my query as index in a QSqlQueryModel. Maybe can u help me with this new question :)

Comment: If you have a question, create a post for it. Ensure that you read [ask] and review the [checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648).